# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on VNSequenceRequestHandler

Tags: objective-c, macos, avfoundation, metal, vision

The following code uses the Vision and AVFoundation frameworks to enable face tracking on the built-in camera on macOS. In some circumstances the code crashes due to `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2)` on a working thread on the queue `com.apple.VN.trackersCollectionManagementQueue (serial)`. The application works as intended as long as no face is detected, but crashes as soon as it detects a face and attempts to track it by the method

```objectivec
[_sequenceRequestHandler performRequests:requests onCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer orientation:exifOrientation error:&error]
```

The method is called inside the AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate method

```objectivec
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection)
```

From what I understand `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means I can't access memory [[1]](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1228.0.2/osfmk/mach/exception_types.h), and the error code (2) `KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE` means that the *specified memory is valid, but does not permit the required forms of access [[2]](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1228.0.2/osfmk/mach/kern_return.h).* A (possibly outdated) technical note explains that *this is caused by the thread trying to write to read-only memory.* [[3]](http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/technotes/tn2004/tn2123.html). From this, I understand the problem is not caused by premature deallocation or memory corruption, but memory access control across threads.

I believe the problem appeared after an update. The crash happens when *Debug Executable* is checked in the scheme editor for Game template projects (Metal, SceneKit, and SpriteKit), but does not crash when used in App and Document App templates. The code also works as intended when adapted to iOS on a physical device. I have tried to isolate the problem by trimming away as much code as possible, and the following files can be added to any template.

**Header file**

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface LSPVision : NSObject <AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer;

- (void)captureFrame;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**Implementation file**

```objectivec
#import "LSPVision.h"
#import <Vision/Vision.h>

@implementation LSPVision
{
    // AVCapture stuff
    AVCaptureSession *_session;
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *_videoDataOutput;
    
    dispatch_queue_t _videoDataOutputQueue;
    CGSize _captureDeviceResolution;
    
    // Vision requests
    NSMutableArray *_detectionRequests; // Array of VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest
    NSMutableArray *_trackingRequests; // Array of VNTrackObjectRequest
    VNSequenceRequestHandler *_sequenceRequestHandler;
    
    BOOL _frameCapture;
}

- (nonnull instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        _session = [self _setupAVCaptureSession];
        
        [self designatePreviewLayerForCaptureSession:_session];
        
        [self _prepareVisionRequest];
        _frameCapture = YES;
        
        if (_session) {
            [_session startRunning];
        }
    }
            return self;
}

# pragma mark Setup AVSession

- (AVCaptureSession *)_setupAVCaptureSession {
    
    AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    AVCaptureDevice *device;
    
    #if defined(TARGET_MACOS)
    if (@available(macOS 10.15, *)) {
        AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession *discoverySession = [AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession discoverySessionWithDeviceTypes:@[AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera] mediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo position:AVCaptureDevicePositionFront];
        
        device = discoverySession.devices.firstObject;
    }
    
    #endif
    
    if (device != nil) {
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:nil];
        
        if ([captureSession canAddInput:deviceInput]) {
            [captureSession addInput:deviceInput];
        }
        
        AVCaptureDeviceFormat *lowestResolution = [self _lowestResolution420Format:device];
        
        if (lowestResolution != nil) {
            if ([device lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
                
                device.activeFormat = lowestResolution;
                [device unlockForConfiguration];
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (device != nil) {
        [self _configureVideoDataOutput:device captureSession:captureSession];
        return captureSession;
    }
    
    NSLog(@"Hold up, something went wrong with AVCaptureSession");
    [self _tearDownAVCapture];
    return nil;
}

- (AVCaptureDeviceFormat *)_lowestResolution420Format:(AVCaptureDevice *)device {
    
    AVCaptureDeviceFormat *lowestResolutionFormat = nil;
    CMVideoDimensions lowestResolutionDimensions = { .height = (int32_t)10000, .width = (int32_t)10000 };
    
    for (AVCaptureDeviceFormat *deviceFormat in device.formats) {
        
        CMFormatDescriptionRef deviceFormatDescription = deviceFormat.formatDescription;
        
        if (CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaSubType(deviceFormatDescription) == (kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange | kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange)) {
            CMVideoDimensions candidateDimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(deviceFormatDescription);
            
            if ((lowestResolutionFormat == nil) || candidateDimensions.width > lowestResolutionDimensions.width) {
                lowestResolutionFormat = deviceFormat;
                lowestResolutionDimensions = candidateDimensions;
                NSLog(@"Device Format: Width: %d, Height: %d", candidateDimensions.width, candidateDimensions.height);
                _captureDeviceResolution.width =  candidateDimensions.width;
                _captureDeviceResolution.height =  candidateDimensions.height;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (lowestResolutionFormat != nil) {
        return lowestResolutionFormat;
    }
    
    return nil;
}

- (void)designatePreviewLayerForCaptureSession:(AVCaptureSession *)session {
    
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *videoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    self.previewLayer = videoPreviewLayer;
    
    videoPreviewLayer.name = @"Camera Preview";
}

- (void)_configureVideoDataOutput:(AVCaptureDevice *)inputDevice captureSession:(AVCaptureSession *)captureSession {
    
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *videoDataOutput = [AVCaptureVideoDataOutput new];
    videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true;
    
    // Create a serial dispatch queue used for the sample buffer delegate as well as when a still image is captured.
    // A serial dispatch queue must be used to guarantee that video frames will be delivered in order.
    dispatch_queue_t videoDataOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.apple-samplecode.VisionFaceTrack", NULL);
    [videoDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:videoDataOutputQueue];
    
    if ([captureSession canAddOutput:videoDataOutput]) {
        [captureSession addOutput:videoDataOutput];
    }
    
    [videoDataOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].enabled = true;
    
    _videoDataOutput = videoDataOutput;
    _videoDataOutputQueue = videoDataOutputQueue;
}

# pragma mark Vision Request

- (void)_prepareVisionRequest {
    
    NSMutableArray *requests = [NSMutableArray array];
    
    VNRequestCompletionHandler handlerBlock =  ^(VNRequest * _Nonnull request, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Handler error: %@", error);
        }
        
        VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest *faceDetectionRequest = (VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest *)request;
        
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            
            for (VNFaceObservation *observation in faceDetectionRequest.results) {
                
                VNTrackObjectRequest *faceTrackingRequest = [[VNTrackObjectRequest alloc] initWithDetectedObjectObservation:observation];
                NSUInteger count = requests.count;
                [requests insertObject:faceTrackingRequest atIndex:count];
            }
            
            self->_trackingRequests = [requests copy];
        });
    };
    
    VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest *faceDetectionRequest = [[VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest alloc] initWithCompletionHandler:handlerBlock];
    
    _detectionRequests = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:faceDetectionRequest];
    _sequenceRequestHandler = [[VNSequenceRequestHandler alloc] init];
}

# pragma mark Delegate functions

// AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
// Handle delegate method callback on receiving a sample buffer.
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
    
    if (_frameCapture == YES) {
        
        NSMutableDictionary *requestHandlerOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        
        CFTypeRef cameraIntrinsicData = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_CameraIntrinsicMatrix, nil);
        if (cameraIntrinsicData != nil) {
            [requestHandlerOptions setObject:CFBridgingRelease(cameraIntrinsicData) forKey:VNImageOptionCameraIntrinsics];
        }
        
        CVImageBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        if (!pixelBuffer) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to obtain a CVPixelBuffer for the current output frame.");
            return;
        }
        
        #if defined(TARGET_MACOS)
        CGImagePropertyOrientation exifOrientation = kCGImagePropertyOrientationLeftMirrored;
        #endif
        
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *requests;
        
        if (_trackingRequests.count > 0) {
            
            requests = _trackingRequests;
            
        } else {
            
            // No tracking object detected, so perform initial detection
            VNImageRequestHandler *imageRequestHandler = [[VNImageRequestHandler alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer orientation:exifOrientation options:requestHandlerOptions];
            
            NSArray *detectionRequests = _detectionRequests;
            if (detectionRequests == nil) {
                return;
            }
            
            [imageRequestHandler performRequests:_detectionRequests error:&error];
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Failed to perform FaceRectangleRequest:  %@", error);
            }
            
            return;
        }
        
        // SequenceRequesthandler results in 10-20% cpu utilization
        [_sequenceRequestHandler performRequests:requests onCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer orientation:exifOrientation error:&error];
        
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to perform SequenceRequest:  %@", error);
            return;
        }
        
        // Setup the next round of tracking
        NSMutableArray *newTrackingRequests = [NSMutableArray array];
        
        for (VNTrackObjectRequest *trackingRequest in requests) {
            
            NSArray *results = trackingRequest.results;
            
            trackingRequest.trackingLevel = VNRequestTrackingLevelFast;
            
            VNDetectedObjectObservation *observation = results[0];
            
            if (![observation isKindOfClass:[VNDetectedObjectObservation class]]) {
                return;
            }
            
            if (!trackingRequest.isLastFrame) {
                if (observation.confidence > 0.3f ) {
                    trackingRequest.inputObservation = observation;
                } else {
                    trackingRequest.lastFrame = true;
                }
                NSUInteger number = newTrackingRequests.count;
                [newTrackingRequests insertObject:trackingRequest atIndex:number];
            }
        }
        
        _trackingRequests = newTrackingRequests;
        
        if (newTrackingRequests.count == 0) {
            // Nothing to track, so abort.
            return;
        }
        
        NSMutableArray *faceLandmarksRequests = [NSMutableArray array];
        
        for (VNTrackObjectRequest* trackingRequest in newTrackingRequests) {
            
            VNRequestCompletionHandler handlerBlock = ^(VNRequest * _Nonnull request, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                if (error != nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Facelandmarks error: %@", error);
                }
                
                VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest *landmarksRequest = (VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest *)request;
                NSArray *results = landmarksRequest.results;
                if (results == nil) {
                    return;
                }
                
                // Perform all UI updates (drawing) on the main queue, not the background queue on which this handler is being called.
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    
                    for (VNFaceObservation *faceObservation in results) {
                        [self _setEyePositionsForFace:faceObservation];
                        //NSLog(@"seeing face");
                    }
                });
            };
            
            VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest *faceLandmarksRequest = [[VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest alloc] initWithCompletionHandler:handlerBlock];
            
            NSArray *trackingResults = trackingRequest.results;
            if (trackingResults == nil) {
                return;
            }
            
            VNDetectedObjectObservation *observation = trackingResults[0];
            if (observation == nil) {
                return;
            }
            
            VNFaceObservation *faceObservation = [VNFaceObservation observationWithBoundingBox:observation.boundingBox];
            faceLandmarksRequest.inputFaceObservations = @[faceObservation];
            
            // Continure to track detected facial landmarks.
            NSUInteger nr = faceLandmarksRequests.count;
            [faceLandmarksRequests insertObject:faceLandmarksRequest atIndex:nr];
            
            VNImageRequestHandler *imageRequestHandler = [[VNImageRequestHandler alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer orientation:exifOrientation options:requestHandlerOptions];
            
            [imageRequestHandler performRequests:faceLandmarksRequests error:&error];
            
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Failed to perform FaceLandmarkRequest: %@", error);
            }
        }
    }
    //_frameCapture = NO;
}

# pragma mark Helper Functions

- (void)captureFrame {
    _frameCapture = YES;
}

- (void)_tearDownAVCapture {
    
    _videoDataOutput = nil;
    _videoDataOutputQueue = nil;
    
}

@end
```

**Debugging**

The crash seems related to Metal, perhaps on multiple threads. The crash happens when the Vision framework (from a working thread) executes Metal Performance Shaders from a private neural network framework (Espresso). Before the crash, there is a deadlock related to command buffers. This ultimately leads to the Address sanitizer reporting `BUS on unknown address`. I assume this is the reason I get `KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE`. Other threads are either executing Metal or simply waiting. I don't know if the semaphores are related to Metal CPU/GPU synchronization or something else. When the code is used with App templates, the Vision framework is run on the main thread and no crash occurs. I can't see how I can address this in any meaningful way except filing a bug report. That being said, my debugging skills leave much to be desired, so any help is strongly appreciated - not only in solving the issue but also in understanding the problem. Address Sanitizer and Thread Sanitizer are turned on for the following output. Due to size constraints the Crash Report kan be read [here](https://gist.github.com/tambarskjelve/977b369e7e5e4e1be61e802861bece88). A crashing project (on my computer) can now be viewed and downloaded from [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bb17kfrymrofj4x/AACFepMhQ95hslygBS2YtIu_a?dl=0). My computer is a 2019 MB Pro 16.

*Console output*

```
ErrorTest1(13661,0x107776e00) malloc: nano zone abandoned due to inability to preallocate reserved vm space.
2020-12-24 09:48:35.709965+0100 ErrorTest1[13661:811227] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2020-12-24 09:48:36.675326+0100 ErrorTest1[13661:811227] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x6030000b7b50> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
2020-12-24 09:48:36.707535+0100 ErrorTest1[13661:811227] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x6030000bb5a0> 30010C1C-93BF-11D8-8B5B-000A95AF9C6A
2020-12-24 09:48:36.845641+0100 ErrorTest1[13661:811227] [] CMIOHardware.cpp:379:CMIOObjectGetPropertyData Error: 2003332927, failed
2020-12-24 09:48:38.717546+0100 ErrorTest1[13661:811794] [logging-persist] cannot open file at line 44580 of [02c344acea]
2020-12-24 09:48:38.717648+0100 ErrorTest1[13661:811794] [logging-persist] os_unix.c:44580: (0) open(/var/db/DetachedSignatures) - Undefined error: 0
2020-12-24 09:48:38.778975+0100 ErrorTest1[13661:811761] [Metal Compiler Warning] Warning: Compilation succeeded with: 

program_source:61:16: warning: unused variable 'input_slice_count'
    const uint input_slice_count = (INPUT_FEATURE_CHANNELS + 3) / 4;
               ^
2020-12-24 09:48:38.779198+0100 ErrorTest1[13661:811812] [Metal Compiler Warning] Warning: Compilation succeeded with: 

program_source:121:24: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'const constant uint' (aka 'const constant unsigned int')
    for(int kd = 0; kd < params.inputFeatureChannels; kd++)  // _ID = 3, RGB
                    ~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-12-24 09:48:38.779441+0100 ErrorTest1[13661:811838] [Metal Compiler Warning] Warning: Compilation succeeded with: 

program_source:121:24: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'const constant uint' (aka 'const constant unsigned int')
    for(int kd = 0; kd < params.inputFeatureChannels; kd++)  // _ID = 3, RGB
                    ~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-12-24 09:48:39.072518+0100 ErrorTest1[13661:811838] [Metal Compiler Warning] Warning: Compilation succeeded with: 

program_source:61:16: warning: unused variable 'input_slice_count'
    const uint input_slice_count = (INPUT_FEATURE_CHANNELS + 3) / 4;
               ^
2020-12-24 09:48:39.073210+0100 ErrorTest1[13661:811842] [Metal Compiler Warning] Warning: Compilation succeeded with: 

program_source:98:16: warning: unused variable 'fm_group'
    const uint fm_group = threadgroup_id.z - splitId * params.simdsPerGroupData;
               ^
program_source:121:24: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'const constant uint' (aka 'const constant unsigned int')
    for(int kd = 0; kd < params.inputFeatureChannels; kd++)  // _ID = 3, RGB
                    ~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-12-24 09:48:39.073538+0100 ErrorTest1[13661:811812] [Metal Compiler Warning] Warning: Compilation succeeded with: 

program_source:98:16: warning: unused variable 'fm_group'
    const uint fm_group = threadgroup_id.z - splitId * params.simdsPerGroupData;
               ^
program_source:121:24: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'const constant uint' (aka 'const constant unsigned int')
    for(int kd = 0; kd < params.inputFeatureChannels; kd++)  // _ID = 3, RGB
                    ~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

*LLDB bt*

```
* thread #5, queue = 'com.apple.VN.trackersCollectionManagementQueue', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x70000deb1ff8)
    frame #0: 0x000000010739db33 libsystem_pthread.dylib`___chkstk_darwin + 55
    frame #1: 0x000000010739dafc libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 20
    frame #2: 0x000000010724277b libMTLCapture.dylib`___lldb_unnamed_symbol2507$$libMTLCapture.dylib + 585
    frame #3: 0x00007fff29f597be MPSNeuralNetwork`___lldb_unnamed_symbol4427$$MPSNeuralNetwork + 1907
    frame #4: 0x00007fff29f5a3c2 MPSNeuralNetwork`___lldb_unnamed_symbol4432$$MPSNeuralNetwork + 756
    frame #5: 0x00007fff29f5aa39 MPSNeuralNetwork`___lldb_unnamed_symbol4435$$MPSNeuralNetwork + 83
    frame #6: 0x00007fff339e50e8 Espresso`Espresso::MPSEngine::mps_convolution_kernel::recreate_kernel() + 230
    frame #7: 0x00007fff339e3c95 Espresso`Espresso::MPSEngine::convolution_kernel_base<Espresso::generic_convolution_kernel>::set_biases(std::__1::shared_ptr<Espresso::blob<float, 1> >) + 455
    frame #8: 0x00007fff339e724b Espresso`Espresso::MPSEngine::convolution_kernel_proxy::set_biases(std::__1::shared_ptr<Espresso::blob<float, 1> >) + 103
    frame #9: 0x00007fff338b3a8f Espresso`Espresso::generic_convolution_kernel::set_biases(std::__1::shared_ptr<Espresso::blob<float, 1> >, std::__1::shared_ptr<Espresso::abstract_batch>) + 49
    frame #10: 0x00007fff338bdee1 Espresso`Espresso::load_network_layers_post_dispatch(std::__1::shared_ptr<Espresso::net> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<Espresso::SerDes::generic_serdes_object> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<Espresso::cpu_context_transfer_algo_t> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<Espresso::net_info_ir_t> const&, bool, Espresso::network_shape const&, Espresso::compute_path, bool, std::__1::shared_ptr<Espresso::blob_storage_abstract> const&) + 5940
    frame #11: 0x00007fff338ba6ee Espresso`Espresso::load_network_layers_internal(std::__1::shared_ptr<Espresso::SerDes::generic_serdes_object>, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<Espresso::abstract_context> const&, Espresso::network_shape const&, std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >*, Espresso::compute_path, bool, std::__1::shared_ptr<Espresso::blob_storage_abstract> const&) + 793
    frame #12: 0x00007fff338c9294 Espresso`Espresso::load_and_shape_network(std::__1::shared_ptr<Espresso::SerDes::generic_serdes_object> const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<Espresso::abstract_context> const&, Espresso::network_shape const&, Espresso::compute_path, std::__1::shared_ptr<Espresso::blob_storage_abstract> const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) + 576
    frame #13: 0x00007fff338cb715 Espresso`Espresso::load_network(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<Espresso::abstract_context> const&, Espresso::compute_path, bool) + 2496
    frame #14: 0x00007fff33d9603c Espresso`EspressoLight::espresso_plan::add_network(char const*, espresso_storage_type_t) + 350
    frame #15: 0x00007fff33daa817 Espresso`espresso_plan_add_network + 294
    frame #16: 0x00007fff30479b9d Vision`+[VNEspressoHelpers createSingleNetworkPlanFromResourceName:usingProcessingDevice:lowPriorityMode:inputBlobNames:outputBlobNames:explicitNetworkLayersStorageType:espressoResources:error:] + 517
    frame #17: 0x00007fff3047992d Vision`+[VNEspressoHelpers createSingleNetworkPlanFromResourceName:usingProcessingDevice:lowPriorityMode:inputBlobNames:outputBlobNames:espressoResources:error:] + 151
    frame #18: 0x00007fff303ce123 Vision`-[VNRPNTrackerEspressoModelCacheManager espressoResourcesFromOptions:error:] + 417
    frame #19: 0x00007fff303ce8c8 Vision`-[VNObjectTrackerRevision2 initWithOptions:error:] + 262
    frame #20: 0x00007fff304152df Vision`__54-[VNTrackerManager _createTracker:type:options:error:]_block_invoke + 207
    frame #21: 0x00000001072fc0b0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #22: 0x000000010730d3b2 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 135
    frame #23: 0x00007fff30414f01 Vision`-[VNTrackerManager _createTracker:type:options:error:] + 261
    frame #24: 0x00007fff30414b52 Vision`-[VNTrackerManager trackerWithOptions:error:] + 509
    frame #25: 0x00007fff304dda4a Vision`-[VNRequestPerformer trackerWithOptions:error:] + 85
    frame #26: 0x00007fff30343ac4 Vision`-[VNTrackingRequest internalPerformRevision:inContext:error:] + 436
    frame #27: 0x00007fff3037fb08 Vision`-[VNRequest performInContext:error:] + 885
    frame #28: 0x00007fff303cd9a1 Vision`VNExecuteBlock + 58
    frame #29: 0x00007fff304dd105 Vision`-[VNRequestPerformer _performOrderedRequests:inContext:error:] + 674
    frame #30: 0x00007fff304dd482 Vision`-[VNRequestPerformer performRequests:inContext:onBehalfOfRequest:error:] + 352
    frame #31: 0x00007fff304dd586 Vision`-[VNRequestPerformer performRequests:inContext:error:] + 60
    frame #32: 0x00007fff304cbf1a Vision`-[VNSequenceRequestHandler _performRequests:onImageBuffer:gatheredForensics:error:] + 293
    frame #33: 0x00007fff304cc122 Vision`-[VNSequenceRequestHandler performRequests:onCVPixelBuffer:orientation:gatheredForensics:error:] + 111
    frame #34: 0x00007fff304cc0aa Vision`-[VNSequenceRequestHandler performRequests:onCVPixelBuffer:orientation:error:] + 28
  * frame #35: 0x0000000106fc5a97 ErrorTest1`-[LSPVision captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:](self=0x0000608000047c20, _cmd="captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:", output=0x00006030000ce770, sampleBuffer=0x0000614000091240, connection=0x00006030000d0c30) at LSPVision.m:246:9
    frame #36: 0x00007fff3786b2e0 AVFCapture`__56-[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput_Tundra _render:sampleBuffer:]_block_invoke + 213
    frame #37: 0x00000001077ff3bb libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib`__wrap_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 203
    frame #38: 0x00000001072fae78 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    frame #39: 0x00000001072fc0b0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #40: 0x00000001073036b7 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 776
    frame #41: 0x0000000107304594 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_invoke + 449
    frame #42: 0x0000000107312217 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 1675
    frame #43: 0x000000010739eb15 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 314
    frame #44: 0x000000010739dae3 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 15
```

### Update

The bug seems to be resolved on macOS Monterey 12.1.

Comment: A bit of a long shot, but I think, after ```CVImageBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);``` you need to call ```CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress``` on the buffer before you start tracking and match that with a ```CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress``` when done.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but it doesn't resolve the issue, unfortunately. From what I understand `CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress` is for CPU access, and is unnecessary and might impact performance if the pixel buffer is accessed by the GPU.

Comment: Hey, @Tambarskjelve, have you been able to resolve this issue? I'm having exactly same crash in [sequenceRequestHandler performRequests] on Macbook Pro Late 2016 and only in debug build. It starts crashing as soon as I add Metal framework to the project, even if there is no code using Metal. If I remove Metal, it works fine. Looks like a bug in macOS to me, but curious to know any workarounds you might have found. I'm running it on BigSur 11.3.

Comment: @const the problem is not resolved, but I can avoid the crash by turning off `Debug Executable` in the Scheme Editor. I did file a bug report, but haven't heard anything back.

Answer (score 1):

More of a comment here, I am trying to reproduce this. I've taken your code as is, but had to comment out `[self _setEyePositionsForFace:faceObservation];` in

```
                    for (VNFaceObservation *faceObservation in results) {
                        //[self _setEyePositionsForFace:faceObservation];
                        //NSLog(@"seeing face");
                    }
```

as you do not give its implementation. However, with that done, I was able to run the code without any issue. To test further I added the logs as below.

```
        // SequenceRequesthandler results in 10-20% cpu utilization
        NSLog(@"aaa");
        [_sequenceRequestHandler performRequests:requests onCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer orientation:exifOrientation error:&error];
        NSLog(@"bbb");
```

as I understand your problem is with `[_sequenceRequestHandler performRequests:requests onCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer orientation:exifOrientation error:&error];` specifically, but I did not run into trouble and the log showed a lot of repeating `aaa` and `bbb`s. To further test I also added an `ok` log as shown below

```
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Failed to perform FaceLandmarkRequest: %@", error);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"ok");
            }
```

and that happily printed together with the `aaa` and `bbb`.

I also hooked up a button as shown below

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    NSLog( @"Button" );
    self.v.captureFrame;
}
```

where `self.v` is an instance of (my) `LSPVision` and I could push the button as much as I'd like without trouble.

I think either the problem lies somewhere else, maybe even in the `_setEyePositionsForFace` that I commented out, or perhaps you can give even more code so I can reproduce it this side?

FWIW here is a sample of the log

```
2020-12-27 09:14:54.147536+0200 MetalCaptureTest[11392:317094] aaa
2020-12-27 09:14:54.184167+0200 MetalCaptureTest[11392:317094] bbb
2020-12-27 09:14:54.268926+0200 MetalCaptureTest[11392:317094] ok
2020-12-27 09:14:54.269374+0200 MetalCaptureTest[11392:317094] aaa
2020-12-27 09:14:54.314135+0200 MetalCaptureTest[11392:316676] Button
2020-12-27 09:14:54.316025+0200 MetalCaptureTest[11392:317094] bbb
2020-12-27 09:14:54.393732+0200 MetalCaptureTest[11392:317094] ok
2020-12-27 09:14:54.394171+0200 MetalCaptureTest[11392:317094] aaa
2020-12-27 09:14:54.432979+0200 MetalCaptureTest[11392:317094] bbb
2020-12-27 09:14:54.496887+0200 MetalCaptureTest[11392:317094] ok
2020-12-27 09:14:54.497389+0200 MetalCaptureTest[11392:317094] aaa
2020-12-27 09:14:54.533118+0200 MetalCaptureTest[11392:317094] bbb
2020-12-27 09:14:54.614813+0200 MetalCaptureTest[11392:317094] ok
2020-12-27 09:14:54.615394+0200 MetalCaptureTest[11392:317094] aaa
2020-12-27 09:14:54.663343+0200 MetalCaptureTest[11392:317094] bbb
2020-12-27 09:14:54.747860+0200 MetalCaptureTest[11392:317094] ok
```

***EDIT***

Thanks, I got the dropbox project and it is working this side. No crashes at all. This is the log.

```
ErrorTest1(11743,0x10900ce00) malloc: nano zone abandoned due to inability to preallocate reserved vm space.
2020-12-27 10:55:10.445333+0200 ErrorTest1[11743:344803] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2020-12-27 10:55:10.471650+0200 ErrorTest1[11743:344803] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x6030000aabc0> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
2020-12-27 10:55:10.528628+0200 ErrorTest1[11743:344803] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x6030000ae130> 30010C1C-93BF-11D8-8B5B-000A95AF9C6A
2020-12-27 10:55:10.608753+0200 ErrorTest1[11743:344803] [] CMIOHardware.cpp:379:CMIOObjectGetPropertyData Error: 2003332927, failed
2020-12-27 10:55:11.408594+0200 ErrorTest1[11743:344873] [logging-persist] cannot open file at line 44580 of [02c344acea]
2020-12-27 10:55:11.408806+0200 ErrorTest1[11743:344873] [logging-persist] os_unix.c:44580: (0) open(/var/db/DetachedSignatures) - Undefined error: 0
2020-12-27 10:55:17.637382+0200 ErrorTest1[11743:344803] seeing face
2020-12-27 10:55:17.838354+0200 ErrorTest1[11743:344803] seeing face
2020-12-27 10:55:17.987583+0200 ErrorTest1[11743:344803] seeing face
2020-12-27 10:55:18.171168+0200 ErrorTest1[11743:344803] seeing face
2020-12-27 10:55:18.320957+0200 ErrorTest1[11743:344803] seeing face
```

FWIW I have latest OS BS 11.1, latest Xcode 12.3 and running this on MB Air 2017. From your description I suspect maybe the multithreading could be a problem but for now my focus is on reproducing it this side.

Comment: Are you using a Game template with _Debug Executable_ checked? It works with App templates for me as well, and `[self _setEyePositionsForFace:faceObservation]` is called after `[_sequenceRequestHandler performRequests:requests onCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer orientation:exifOrientation error:&error]` and is never called when the application crashes. A crashing project (on my computer) can now be viewed and downloaded from [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bb17kfrymrofj4x/AACFepMhQ95hslygBS2YtIu_a?dl=0).

Comment: @Tambarskjelve ok I got it working this side. Still no error. Look at the edit to my answer.

Comment: @Tambarskjelve you've cleared the derived data / project cache / project build folder and recompiled everything? Just in case there is some left over stuff from earlier somewhere

Comment: Yes, deleted derived data / project cache and project build folder several times. I guess it would be hard to reproduce with the exact same project, OS and Xcode version. The console outputs are identical, except mine reports `[Metal Compiler Warning] Warnings` in addition (as seen above). The computer is a MB Pro 16 (2019).

Comment: Yes I did side by side comparison of output logs but was none the wiser. My MB is NOT retina fwiw. I'll test this on a retina computer as well just to see.

Answer (score 1):

I also got an unexplainable crash using `Vision` in one app, but not in another one I created for testing. Turns out enabling "Metal API Validation" made the problem go away for me. I do have several custom Metal kernels in my app, but I still don't understand what the root problem is.

[image: Metal API Validation]

Comment: Thanks, just tested this, and `Metal API Validation` does not affect the outcome. The application only crashes when `Debug Executable` is checked.